# Google Custom search API returning Access Not Configured

Tags: objective-c, google-custom-search

We are calling API by url:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=CUSTOM_SEARCH_ID&q=flower

getting error in reponse:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
}
```

WE have enabled Custom Search API and Google + API. Still getting above error. Should we needto enable some other API too?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm repeating here the answer I gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708115/which-apis-are-needed-to-get-enabled-for-google-custom-search)).

No, I believe that custom search API is the only API that you need to enable.

So, I would consider whether you have the right key and CSE ID.

To verify your CSE ID, do a test query from here (fill in ):
https://console.developers.google.com/project/PROJECT_ID/apiui/api/customsearch/method/search.cse.list

If your query works there, but still doesn't work in your code, then perhaps the issue is your key. If you are just doing a simple URL request (as you show in your Q), then I would expect you are using a server key. And, of course, the key you are using must be from the same project where you have enabled the CSE API.