# Which API's are needed to get enabled for Google Custom search?

Tags: objective-c, google-custom-search

We are calling API by URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=CUSTOM_SEARCH_ID&q=flower
```

Getting error in reponse:

```
"error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "accessNotConfigured", "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." }
```

We have enabled Custom Search API and Google + API. Still getting above error. should we need to enable some other API too?

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Custom search API returning Access Not Configured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706642/google-custom-search-api-returning-access-not-configured)

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe that custom search API is the only API that you need to enable.

So, I would consider whether you have the right key and CSE ID.

To verify your CSE ID, do a test query from here (fill in ):
https://console.developers.google.com/project/PROJECT_ID/apiui/api/customsearch/method/search.cse.list

If your query works there, but still doesn't work in your code, then perhaps the issue is your key.  If you are just doing a simple URL request (as you show in your Q), then I would expect you are using a server key.  And, of course, the key you are using must be from the same project where you have enabled the CSE API.

Comment: I am enabling the service in API List and getting the response in test query but no response in the app

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard
In the dashboard screen there is an Enable API link(near Dashboard heading)
Choose the API you want to enable.
The enabled API will be listed in the dashboard.
Call the API by URL and check.